# With iOS development, is there any way for an app to obtain the phone number that is currently calling a phone?

Tags: ios

When someone calls a user's phone, I want the app to be able to store the phone number as a variable in order to perform certain function with it. From what I've read, there is nothing in the iOS library that allows you to do that and any other custom made method wouldn't make it passed Apple's approval process.

Am I correct with this? Is there no way for an app to do something with a number that is calling a phone? Is there any loophole - such as the app to take a screenshot of the phone when it the phone is getting called and be able to see the number based on pixels - as opposed to something that systematically sees the phone number? Would a concept like that be possible?

Comment: It's certainly not possible without jailbreaking.  With jailbreaking, it *may* be possible.

Comment: Then how to truecaller did @Avi ??

Comment: Truecaller uses the addressbook @hatim. 

It uses this feature: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201229

Truecaller does not obtain the phone number, it just sees the addressbook not having it as a contact. A smart way to avoid the sandboxing.

Comment: But doesn't Truecaller obtain the phone number at some point in order to check it's database to see if it is a spam number or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can detect a Call, but only if your app is running in the foreground. [Using Core Telephony Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/index.html).

Depending on your use of this information, Apple will accept/reject your app.

The `CTCallCenter` will allow you to detect any calls that are started or already in progress.

**2nd: best of my knowledge:**
iOS does not allow you to access call history. There are no service or api provided by Apple. 
But it is possible to get information about current caller of your phone. [Access iPhone call history](https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)
I think you won't get approved by app store. IF you want's to use for your private purpose (without publishing to app store) then you may

Comment: Thank you. I would need the app to do something the moment the call comes in as the phone is ringing, not after. However like you mentioned, I believe Apple will reject the app so I'm not going to continue with the idea I had.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there isn't any API calls for that. But some people have mentioned that there is a SQLite database stored on the device which keeps track of the call log. Please refer the following websites for details.

1. https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Call_History_Database
2. https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/

If you manage to get that, then you can query the DB for the call history.

I'm not certain whether this works as the post is quite old (published in 2011). Furthermore, Apple contains a list of app rejection criteria if you try to use information outside the allowed. So, I recommend that you go through Apple's documentation before you proceed with your app.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'm sure there's a way to get around it but like you said, the app would most likely get rejected by Apple so I won't bother.